# Convert string from config file to import path

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a config file here:

```
log:
  filename: 'log'
  format: '%(levelname)s:%(message)s'
  level: 'logging.INFO'
```

Which I am trying to use in my logging configuration here:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=str(config['log']['filename']),
    format=str(config['log']['format']),
    level=str(config['log']['level'])
)
```

However, I get this error presumably because I am passing in a string, but the logging level needs a path within the logging module.

```
ValueError: Unknown level: 'logging.INFO'
```

How can I convert this to a module path or is there a different approach I should use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `logging.getLevelName('INFO')` to convert from a string to a log level (which is an integer code). So as long as you can change your config file to:

```
log:
  filename: 'log'
  format: '%(levelname)s:%(message)s'
  level: 'INFO'
```

This should work

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=str(config['log']['filename']),
    format=str(config['log']['format']),
    level=logging.getLevelName(config['log']['level'])
)
```

PS Do you need the str() casts?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and hacky way:**

You can use `eval()`. It executes python code in strings. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval))

Example:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=eval('logging.INFO')
)

logging.info('Works!')
```

Outputs:

```
INFO:root:Works!
```

Although this works, using `eval` is considered bad practice because you can execute any Python code so it's not secure i.e. can pass anything in config and it will be executed in your application. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

---

**Safer approach:**

In your config file you can pass 'your' defined level keywords such as `info` or `warning` etc. ([All levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels))

Example config:

```
log:
  filename: 'log'
  format: '%(levelname)s:%(message)s'
  level: 'info'
```

In code, you can create a mapping between those words and actual logging level and then instantiate the logger with that.

```py
import logging

#Create mappings
level_mapping = {'info': logging.INFO, 'warning': logging.WARNING}

#Read your config file
config = {} 

#When passed logging level doesn't exist in mappings, raise an exception
if config['log']['level'] not in level_mapping:
    raise ValueError('Invalid logging level passed in config!!!')

#Instantiate
logging.basicConfig(
    level=level_mapping[config['log']['level']]
)
```

This way you have a whitelist of accepted levels in your application.